# Browser.get() not working using Selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am really bad at coding and am trying to cop a 3070. I tried to create this bot, and the browser opens, but the website link does not open (if that makes sense). Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# For Chrome
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "--user-data-dir=C:/Users/ajith/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    "C:/Users/ajith/OneDrive/Desktop/bot/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Bestbuy 3090 Page
browser.get(
    "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3070-8gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-graphics-card-dark-platinum-and-black/6429442.p?skuId=6429442")` ` `
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\ajith\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\codething.py", line 11, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
  File "C:\Users\ajith\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(

Comment: THere is a lot more, but i just put a part of it.

Comment: If there's an error message, you should post all of it with the question. With Python error messages, more times than not, the helpful info is at the end.